# Check if two vectors are on the same side and in between two other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I have directional vectors $a, b, c, d$ in vector 2 space as seen in the images below. Unfortunately I don't have the sufficient vocabulary to explain this in more mathematical terms. In rough terms I need to check if vector $c$ and $d$ are "on the same side in between" vector $a$ and $b$ as in the first and second image, or they are not as in the third image. How would I do this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It can be done by calculating the *cross-ratio* of the spanned lines in the projective plane.

Comment: You have a few options. For example, check the angle between the vectors. Another option is to normalize the vectors so they are all of length 1. We mark these normalized vectors $\tilde{a},\tilde{b}...$. Then check whether $\tilde{c}, \tilde{d}$ are a convex combination of $\tilde{a},\tilde{b}$, meaning if you can express them as $\tilde{c}=\lambda \tilde{a}+(1-\lambda) \tilde{b}$, where $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates of $c$ in the basis $(a, b)$ are $\frac{\det(c,b)}{\det(a, b)}$
and $\frac{\det(a, c)}{\det(a, b)}$ (these are Cramer's formulas). If both are positive, the vector is in the positive cone as in figure 1 and 3. Otherwise it is not in the positive cone.

Comment: Thank you very much! What would be the definition of a positive cone?

Comment: Well  here it would be the set $K=\{\lambda a + \mu b; \lambda, \mu \in ]0,+\infty[\}$

Comment: But in more rough terms? I don't understand this unfortunately.

Comment: In more rough terms it is the domain between the half lines defined by the two vectors.

Comment: Hey after giving this another look, I wonder why is vector $d$ not in the solution? As is changing $d$ doesn't change the result, which it should right? Did you make a typo by chance?

Comment: With my answer you can say if c is in the positve cone of a, b or not (yes or no). Do the same with d (yes or no). It gives two booleans. If they are equal, the two vectors are on the same side.

Comment: I'm guessing in simple words positive cone means the smaller cone between two vectors. And the larger cone is a negative cone (?).  If so your solution only works when both vectors are in the positive cone (smaller cone) as in the first image. But what if they are both in larger cone as in the second image? Then the determinants will either be both negative, or one of them be negative. I need to cover the case with larger cone.

Comment: Oh sorry I can calculate if both are in negative cone by simply checking if both determinants for both vectors are NOT positive.

Comment: Out of interest, are you programming this in a programming language?

Comment: Yes I do in fact! Why? :)

Answer (score 0):

Find $\angle ba$, $\angle ca$, and  $\angle $da. If $|\angle ba|$ is greater than both  $|\angle ca|$| and $ |\angle da|$, both vectors are in the positive cone.

Comment: Is $\angle ba$ angle between $b$ and $a$?

Comment: @LennyWhite yes